# Standardized file or data transfer over WebRTC Data Channel

Tags: webrtc, file-transfer, data-transfer, rtcdatachannel

We are developing a webrtc application that uses data channel in order to transfer data, especially file.

After some investigation, I have came up with solutions in following links, 
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-file-broadcast-works.html

Both solutions are working just fine and I am planning to use approachs in there, but the problem in here is, both solutions wrote a file transfer protocol for chunking and re-constructing the file. In this approach, receiver side must know the protocol and apply requirements of that protocol.

I am planning to convert file to data url and split into chunks. In every message, I will send **data chunk**, **current index of chunk** and **total number of chunks**, but this way I am writing my protocol and I can not expect a third party application to understand my protocol.

What I want to ask is, is there any standardization for data transfer over webrtc channel? Is there any RFC for it?

Thanks and regards,
Ugurcan

Comment: When would this be necessary? Usually the same software sits at both ends.

Comment: In my solution, both ends have same software too, so this is not an issue. But, in order to communicate with all data channel implementations, it would be nice to have an universal, standardized approach.

Comment: What would be a situation where the same software is not on both ends?